# Android: Is there a Tree Package (Datastructure) I can use?

Tags: android, data-structures, tree

I'm trying to convert a Java Program to Android. I created a new xml Interface and most of the core logic is still running but since Swing is not present in Android  i'm missing the class javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode in particular.
Is there an easy way to replace the class with something equivalent in Android?

Thanks in advance!
Taber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Tree view on Android, so there is no directly comparable class.

But, if you need to use a tree-like data structure to display it's data in UI, for example in [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), then you can use [`CursorTreeAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html).